# problem with js loops and array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have a question about js loops and how they really work. I'm looping trough an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const array = [{value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}];
```

The loop just updates the value of every element:

```
array.forEach(el => {
        el.value = 1;
        console.log(array)
})
```

The thing that I don't understand is why the output looks like this:

```
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}]
```

And not like this:

```
[{value: 1}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 0}]
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 1}]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The output of the code you provided is actually the same as the last code block!

Comment: nothing wrong with the code. can u check again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to look at the output on the dev tools on Chrome, and on the dev tools, you see a reference to the array. meaning that at the end of the execution all the items have value = 1, so the dev tools shows your the same reference to the array.

To see the actual values at the moment of execution (instead of reference) use `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
const array = [{value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}];

array.forEach(el => {
        el.value = 1;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
});
```